# Button that rotates to a different link each time

Tags: javascript, button, hyperlink

I would like to create a button that points to 1 of 6 different webpages each time it is clicked. 
For example, Visitor 1 clicks on the button and it goes to Website A; 
Visitor 2 clicks on the same button and it goes to Website B, etc. 
Once it reaches the end of the list of 6, it starts over.

So it's a ROTATING list, rather than a random list. I've found code for a random list, but need rotating. Can you help me?

Thank you so much for your wisdom!

Comment: Please provide code examples that show what you've tried and where your problem is. see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I believe the premise of your use case is flawed. It isn't possible to change the behavior of a page in a different browser session on a different client in a different location from within JavaScript. You'll need to do that server side.